# Mathplotlib adding dates automatically

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Why is mathplotlib adding dates to the plot. E.g: 2023-02-15

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['YearMonth'] = [202303,202302,202301,202212,202211]
df['total_burgers'] = [800,900,1200,1100,1000]
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format='%Y%m')

x=df['YearMonth']
y1=df['total_burgers']
plt.plot(x, y1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib automatically choose xtick you can define like that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['YearMonth'] = [202303,202302,202301,202212,202211]
df['total_burgers'] = [800,900,1200,1100,1000]
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format='%Y%m')

x = df['YearMonth']
y1 = df['total_burgers']
plt.plot(x, y1)

plt.xticks(x, x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I mean its adding highlighted dates above. I need the dates I passed to show up

Comment: Just use ```plt.xticks(x, x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), rotation=45)``` I modified answer.